# Grouping and heading pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe of securities and computed a 'liquidity score' in the last column, where 1 = liquid, 2 = less liquid, and 3 = illiquid. I want to group the securities (dynamically) by their liquidity. Is there a way to group them and include some kind of header for each group? How can this be best achieved. Below is the code and some exa[image]mple, how it is supposed to look like.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['XS123', 'US3312', 'DE405'], 'Currency':['EUR', 'EUR', 'USD'], 'Liquidity score':[2,3,1]})
df = df.sort_values(by=["Liquidity score"])
print(df)

# 1 = liquid, 2 = less liquid,, 3 = illiquid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add labels for liquidity score

The following replaces labels for numbers in Liquidity score:

```
df['grp'] = df['Liquidity score'].replace({1:'Liquid', 2:'Less liquid', 3:'Illiquid'})
```

#### Headers for each group

As per your comment, find below a solution to do this.
Let's illustrate this with a small data example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['XS223', 'US934', 'US905', 'XS224', 'XS223'], 'Currency':['EUR', 'USD', 'USD','EUR','EUR',]})
```

Insert a header on specific rows using `np.insert`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=["Liquid", ""], axis=0))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 2, values=["Less liquid", ""], axis=0))
df.columns = ['ID', 'Currency']
```

Using Pandas styler, we can add a background color, change font weight to bold and align the text to the left.

```
df.style.hide_index().set_properties(subset = pd.IndexSlice[[0,2], :], **{'font-weight' : 'bold', 'background-color' : 'lightblue', 'text-align': 'left'})
```

[image]

Comment: But i want the "liquid", "less liquid" etc. as a heading for each group. Basically, the user can select the liquidity level via checkboxes (also two or more, or a mix of them) and the output should a "block" of the various securities based on their liquidity. Just as in the screenshot from excel I have attached. Maybe its just not possible?

Comment: @MANGo 92: Please have a look, curious to know if this resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column like this:

```
df['group'] = np.select(
    [
        df['Liquidity score'].eq(1),
        df['Liquidity score'].eq(2)
    ],
    [
        'Liquid','Less liquid'
    ],
    default='Illiquid'
)
```

And try setting as index, so you can filter using the index:

```
df.set_index(['grouping','ID'], inplace=True)
df.loc['Less liquid',:]
```

[image]